# Why does my Union procedure of set A and set B return set A and nothing else?

Tags: set, scheme, lisp, sicp

I am working on SICP exercise 2.59, which asks the reader to *"implement the union-set operation for the unordered-list representation of sets"*.  The union of two sets - denoted by A∪B - is the set of elements which are in A, in B, or in both A and B.

Here is the code I wrote to perform this operation:

```lisp
(define (element-of-set? x set)
  (cond ((null? set) #f)
        ((equal? x (car set)) #t)
        (else (element-of-set? x (cdr set)))))

(define (union a b)
  (cond ((null? a) b)
        ((null? b) a)
        (element-of-set? (car b) a)
          (union a (cdr b))
        (else (cons (car b) a))))
```

I tested it on sets of odds and evens, `(define odds '(1 3 5)) (define evens '(0 2 4 6)) (union odds evens)`, and got an output of `(1 3 5)` when the expected output was `(1 3 5 0 2 4 6)`.  Can anyone explain why I get this output and how to rewrite the code to get the expected output?

Here is an example of a working union procedure:

```lisp
(define (union-set s1 s2) 
   (if (null? s1) 
     s2 
     (let 
       ((e (car s1))) 
       (union-set 
         (cdr s1) 
         (if (element-of-set? e s2) s2 (cons e s2))))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

- You forgot a couple of `()` in the third condition
- In the last condition we also have to call the recursion

This should fix it:

```
(define (union a b)
  (cond ((null? a) b)
        ((null? b) a)
        ((element-of-set? (car b) a)
         (union a (cdr b)))
        (else (cons (car b) (union a (cdr b))))))
```

Alternatively, if you want to preserve the *exact* same order as in the sample output of the question:

```
(define (union a b)
  (cond ((null? a) b)
        ((null? b) a)
        ((not (element-of-set? (car a) b))
         (cons (car a) (union (cdr a) b)))
        (else (union (cdr a) b))))
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `else` clause, you don't call `union` so you lose everything in `cdr b`.

Maybe:

```
(else (union (cons (car b) a) (cdr b)))
```